# Maya.cmds.warning() relying on a maya's logger?

Tags: debugging, logging, maya

I'm trying to figure out how I can stop maya from displaying some messages such as info and warnings.
it sounds like a job for the logger by just settings its level but it doesn't seem to affect the commands such as cmds.warning()

are those commands even using the logger?
is maya playing some trick on use by force setting the logger in the command itself?

any info is appreciated!
Cheers!